# How to move between backlog items without going back to list in Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

If I'm going through a list of work items (backlog) in Azure DevOps (TFS) using the DevOps web app, is there a way to move through the list of items while viewing each item in a window, without going back to the list and clicking on the next item? In other words, I want to click on the first item in the back log (it opens in a window) and view its details, then navigate directly to the next item in the list, and so on, until I'm done with the list, without first having to go back to the list between stories/items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your descriptions, what you are looking for seems to be buttons like "→" and "←" to quick move forward next or backward previous work item in the backlog list.

**This is not available** at the moment. However, as a  workaround you could **use query** to list your backlog items, there should be a **preview window**.

You could navigate your work item in the left list of query result and check  the work item details in the right or bottom .

[image]

If above workaround not help you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From either the *backlog* or *workitems* view you can create a query.

[image]

From there you can get a split view with both a list and the workitems you are dealing with.

[image]